# ORDER BY complicated expressions in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sorting

I am trying to ORDER BY a difference between 2 double values (which are aliased columns), but it does not see the aliased columns.

Example:

```
SELECT COALESCE(
  ROUND(
   SUM(amount * currency1.rate / currency2.rate)
   , 4)
 , 0) AS first_amount,
SUM(
   (SELECT
     COALESCE(
       ROUND(
         SUM(table2.amount * currency3.rate / currency2.rate)
       , 4)
     , 0)
   FROM table2
     JOIN currencies currency3
       ON currency3.id = table2.currency_id
   WHERE table2.date BETWEEN table1.start_date AND table1.end_date
   )
 ) AS second_amount
 FROM table1
 JOIN currencies currency1
   ON currency3.id = table1.currency_id
 JOIN currencies currency2
   ON currency3.id = 123  # some hardcoded ID
 ORDER BY first_amount - second_amount ASC
```

Postgres tells me that column first_amount does not exist.
Reading the documentation, I saw that Postgres 9.0 does not allow expressions with aliased columns.

How can I solve the problem by sorting all the stuff I need in the correct manner ?

Comment: if nothing works, try a view)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A column alias cannot be used directly in the where or order by clause. You need to wrap this in a derived table.

```
select *
from (
  ... your original query goes here ...
) as t
ORDER BY first_amount - second_amount ASC;
```

Comment: ... you type faster than me.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it looks like I missed the simple answer, by going deeper into more complicated SQL ! It works !